# How to calculate Big O for this algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o, function-calls

I want to find the Big O of method1.

```
public static void method1(int[] array, int n)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < n - 1; index++)
    {
        int mark = privateMethod1(array, index, n - 1);
        int temp = array[index];
        array[index] = array[mark];
        array[mark] = temp;
    } // end for
} // end method1

public static int privateMethod1(int[] array, int first, int last)
{
    int min = array[first];
    int indexOfMin = first;
    for (int index = first + 1; index <= last; index++)
    {
        if (array[index] < min)
        {
            min = array[index];
            indexOfMin = index;
        } // end if
    } // end for
    return indexOfMin;
} // end privateMethod1
```

My thinking is that we need not care about privateMethod1, is this true? Do we need not worry about function calls while calculating Big O and just consider other factors like assignment operations in our method1?

Thanks.

Comment: No, you definitely have to take the running time of other functions into account when they are called within your algorithm.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for letting me know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only operations that run in constant time, `O(1)`, can be considered *basic operations* in your analysis of the running time of your algorithm; in this specific case, finding an upper asymptotic bound for you algorithm (Big-O notation). The number of iterations in the `for` loop of your method `privateMethod1` depends on `index` in `method1` (which itself depends on `n`) as well as on `n`, and does clearly not run in constant time.

Hence, we need to include `privateMethod1` in our Big-O analysis of your algorithm. We'll treat all other operations, such as assignments and `if` statements as basic operations.

> Treated as basic operations in our analysis:
>
> ```
> /* in 'method1' */
> int temp = array[index];
> array[index] = array[mark];
> array[mark] = temp;
>
> /* in 'privateMethod1' */
> int min = array[first];
> int indexOfMin = first;
>
> //...
>
> if (array[index] < min)
> {
>     min = array[index];
>     indexOfMin = index;
> }
> ```

---

With this cleared up, you can analyse the algorithm using Sigma notation: the outer sum describes the `for` loop in `method1`, and the inner loop describes the `for` loop in `privateMethod1`, and the `1` generalizes "the cost" of all basic operations in the inner `for` loop.

[image]

Hence, an upper asymptotic bound for your algorithm `method1` is `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

> My thinking is that we need not care about privateMethod1,is this true?

No, you are wrong. You need to care about other function calls while calculating complexity. `privateMethod1` runs in `O(n)` time since at worst case `fist` will be `0` and `last` is always `n - 1`. So your overall loop, i.e. `method1` runs in `O(n ^ 2)` time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have another query as well. In this case, what would the basic operation be in method1? Would it be the function call to privateMethod or would it simply be the assignment operation? I mean which is more important while calculating Big O?

Comment: And also how can you say that in worst case `first` will be 0? I mean `first` is dependent on the value of index coming in from method1, and since index has to iterate from 0 through (n-1), there probably is no worst case or best case right?

Comment: @rohitkrishna094 both function call and assignment are basic operation, both of them take `O(1)` time. A function call normally means create a function stack frame, copy the parameters and return operation. These are independent of the execution statements, i.e. the body of function. The first call to `privateMethod1` will have `first = 0`. In this case the loop inside the function runs maximum number of times, i.e. `n`. So clearly this is the worst case situation.